# Is this elliptic fibration over a Riemann surface locally trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider a holomorphic submersion $p: M \to S$ from a compact complex surface to a compact complex curve. For each $x \in S$, the preimage $p^{-1}(x)$ is an elliptic curve, possibly distinct for different $x \in S$. If we additionally assume that $p: M \to S$ is a $C^\infty$ trivial $T^2$-bundle over $S$, can we infer that $p: M \to S$ is a holomorphic fiber bundle or, more expansively, a holomorphically trivial bundle?

Comment: I guess $C^\infty$-triviality follows from Ehresmann's Theorem.

Comment: @Sasha Locally sure, but I understood the question to mean globally smoothly trivial

Comment: The question asked in the text does not match the title. Very unclear post.